# how to flatten json file in nodejs using recursion

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, recursion

I have a very complex nested json file and i need to traverse it using **recursion**
what I need is

1. assign the value of innermost value to its parent key
2. remove the innermost key and value
3. remove empty objects

I have tried many ways and I am new to javascript world and could not come up with the right solution.
the json i have is nested as below

```
      {
         "Changes_Only": {
                "_text": "some value"
              },
              "Legal_Employee_Id": {},
            "EmployeeData": {
              "OBJECT_ACTION_ID": {
               "_text": "some value"
              },
              "Employee": {
                "PersonID": {
                  "_text": "some value"
                },
                "PersonID_OLD": {},
                "PersonNumber": {
                  "_text": "some value"
                },
                "PersonNumber_OLD": {},
                "StartDate": {
                  "_text": "some value"
                },
                "StartDate_OLD": {},
                "PersonType": {
                  "_text": "some value"
                },
                "PersonType_OLD": {},
                "DateofBirth": {
                  "_text": "some value"
                },
                "DateofBirth_OLD": {},
                "HireDate": {
                  "_text": "some value"
                },
                "HireDate_OLD": {},
                "WorkEmail": {
                  "_text": "some value"
                },
                "WorkEmail_OLD": {},
                "FirstName": {
                  "_text": "some value"
                },
                "FirstName_OLD": {},
                "LastName": {
                  "_text": "some value"
                },
                "LastName_OLD": {}
              },
              "NationalIDHT": {
                "NtionalIDData": {
                  "NationalIDValues": {
                    "NationalType": {
                      "_text": "some value"
                    },
                    "NationalIDNumber": {
                      "_text": "some value"
                    }
                  }
                }
              },
              "AssignmentHT": {
                "AssignmentData": {
                  "Assignment": {
                    "PersonNumber": {
                      "_text": "some value"
                    },
                    "PersonNumber_OLD": {},
                    "WorkerNumber": {
                      "_text": "some value"
                    },
                    "WorkerNumber_OLD": {},
                    "Gender": {
                      "_text": "some value"
                    },
                    "Gender_OLD": {},
                    "ActionName": {
                      "_text": "some value"
                    },
                    "ActionName_OLD": {},
                    "HourlySalaried": {
                      "_text": "some value"
                    },
                    "HourlySalaried_OLD": {},
                    "SalaryBasis": {
                      "_text": "some value"
                    },
                    "SalaryBasis_OLD": {},
                    "ManagerPersonNumber": {
                      "_text": "some value"
                    },
                    "ManagerPersonNumber_OLD": {},
                    "ManagerDisplayName": {
                      "_text": "some value"
                    },
                    "ManagerDisplayName_OLD": {},
                    "AssignmentCategory": {
                      "_text": "some value"
                    },
                    "AssignmentCategory_OLD": {},
                    "AsgState": {
                      "_text": "some value"
                    },
                    "AsgState_OLD": {},
                    "JobCode": {
                      "_text": "some value"
                    },
                    "JobCode_OLD": {},
                    "Desgination": {
                      "_text": "some value"
                    },
                    "Desgination_OLD": {},
                    "Grade": {
                      "_text": "some value"
                    },
                    "Grade_OLD": {},
                    "Levele-Grade": {
                      "_text": "some value"
                    },
                    "Levele-Grade_OLD": {},
                    "Department": {
                      "_text": "some value"
                    },
                    "Department_OLD": {},
                    "EmployeeType": {
                      "_text": "some value"
                    },
                    "EmployeeType_OLD": {},
                    "BusinessUnit": {
                      "_text":"some value"
                    },
                    "BusinessUnit_OLD": {},
                    "BaseLocation": {
                      "_text":"some value"
                    },
                    "BaseLocation_OLD": {},
                    "PhysicalWorkAddress": {
                      "_text":"some value"
                    }
                    }
                  }
                }
              }
            }
```

the json which i need as below also help me remove the empty objects

```
{
         "Changes_Only":  "some value",
          
            "EmployeeData": {
              "OBJECT_ACTION_ID":  "some value",
              "Employee": {
                "PersonID": "some value",
                "PersonNumber":  "some value",
                "StartDate":  "some value",
                "PersonType":  "some value",
                "DateofBirth":  "some value",
                "HireDate":  "some value",
                "WorkEmail":  "some value",
                "FirstName":  "some value",
                "LastName":  "some value"
              },
              "NationalIDHT": {
                "NtionalIDData": {
                  "NationalIDValues": {
                    "NationalType":  "some value",
                    "NationalIDNumber":  "some value"
                  }
                }
              },
              "AssignmentHT": {
                "AssignmentData": {
                  "Assignment": {
                    "PersonNumber": "some value",
                    "WorkerNumber": "some value",
                    "Gender":  "some value",
                    "ActionName": "some value",
                    "HourlySalaried": "some value",
                    "SalaryBasis": "some value",
                    "ManagerPersonNumber": "some value",
                    "ManagerDisplayName":  "some value",
                    "AssignmentCategory":  "some value",
                    "AsgState":  "some value",
                    "JobCode":  "some value",
                    "Desgination":  "some value",
                    "Grade":  "some value",
                    "Levele-Grade":  "some value",
                    "Department":  "some value",
                    "EmployeeType":  "some value",
                    "BusinessUnit":  "some value",
                    "BaseLocation":  "some value",
                    "PhysicalWorkAddress": "some value"
                    }
                  }
                }
              }
            }
```

Comment: I have edited it thank you @BiswaBhusan

Comment: Can you check the validation here https://jsoneditoronline.org/

Comment: thank you @BiswaBhusan I have done it now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this I am just correcting @Konstantin Pribluda

```
const r = { ...} // Input JSON
JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(r).replace(/{\s*"_text":\s*("[^"]*")\s*}/g, "$1").replace(/"[^"]*"\s*:\s*{},/g,""))
```

Second, replace for empty {}

Answer (score 1):

Actually you do not need JSON parsing here -   you may get away with regex. replacing {"_text": "some value"}   with just "some value"  will do the trick.

Like this:

```
str.replace(/{\s*"_text":\s*("[^"]*")\s*}/, "$1")
```

will take care of

`"PersonNumber": { "_text": "some value" },`

and

```
str.replace(/"[^"]*"\s*:\s*{},/,"")
```

will get rid of empty attributes

Comment: It is not making any changes on the JSON string

Comment: It is changing but for only one occurrence corrected on my answer

Comment: add /mg  on end of regular expression

Answer (score 0):

Here is an answer that doesn't rely on string manipulation and uses object-scan.

String manipulation has it's place, but here it could cause issues (i.e. pruning objects that become empty after their properties are pruned). So this answer should be preferred over those using string manipulation

```js
// const objectScan = require('object-scan');

const input = {"Changes_Only":{"_text":"some value"},"Legal_Employee_Id":{},"EmployeeData":{"OBJECT_ACTION_ID":{"_text":"some value"},"Employee":{"PersonID":{"_text":"some value"},"PersonID_OLD":{},"PersonNumber":{"_text":"some value"},"PersonNumber_OLD":{},"StartDate":{"_text":"some value"},"StartDate_OLD":{},"PersonType":{"_text":"some value"},"PersonType_OLD":{},"DateofBirth":{"_text":"some value"},"DateofBirth_OLD":{},"HireDate":{"_text":"some value"},"HireDate_OLD":{},"WorkEmail":{"_text":"some value"},"WorkEmail_OLD":{},"FirstName":{"_text":"some value"},"FirstName_OLD":{},"LastName":{"_text":"some value"},"LastName_OLD":{}},"NationalIDHT":{"NtionalIDData":{"NationalIDValues":{"NationalType":{"_text":"some value"},"NationalIDNumber":{"_text":"some value"}}}},"AssignmentHT":{"AssignmentData":{"Assignment":{"PersonNumber":{"_text":"some value"},"PersonNumber_OLD":{},"WorkerNumber":{"_text":"some value"},"WorkerNumber_OLD":{},"Gender":{"_text":"some value"},"Gender_OLD":{},"ActionName":{"_text":"some value"},"ActionName_OLD":{},"HourlySalaried":{"_text":"some value"},"HourlySalaried_OLD":{},"SalaryBasis":{"_text":"some value"},"SalaryBasis_OLD":{},"ManagerPersonNumber":{"_text":"some value"},"ManagerPersonNumber_OLD":{},"ManagerDisplayName":{"_text":"some value"},"ManagerDisplayName_OLD":{},"AssignmentCategory":{"_text":"some value"},"AssignmentCategory_OLD":{},"AsgState":{"_text":"some value"},"AsgState_OLD":{},"JobCode":{"_text":"some value"},"JobCode_OLD":{},"Desgination":{"_text":"some value"},"Desgination_OLD":{},"Grade":{"_text":"some value"},"Grade_OLD":{},"Levele-Grade":{"_text":"some value"},"Levele-Grade_OLD":{},"Department":{"_text":"some value"},"Department_OLD":{},"EmployeeType":{"_text":"some value"},"EmployeeType_OLD":{},"BusinessUnit":{"_text":"some value"},"BusinessUnit_OLD":{},"BaseLocation":{"_text":"some value"},"BaseLocation_OLD":{},"PhysicalWorkAddress":{"_text":"some value"}}}}}};

const rewrite = (data) => {
  objectScan(['**'], {
    breakFn: ({ value, gparent, gproperty }) => {
      if (typeof value === 'string') {
        gparent[gproperty] = value;
      }
    },
    filterFn: ({ value, parent, property }) => {
      if (value instanceof Object && Object.keys(value).length === 0) {
        delete parent[property];
      }
    }
  })(data);
};

console.log(rewrite(input));
// => undefined
console.log(input);
/* => {
  Changes_Only: 'some value',
  EmployeeData: {
    OBJECT_ACTION_ID: 'some value',
    Employee: {
      PersonID: 'some value',
      PersonNumber: 'some value',
      StartDate: 'some value',
      PersonType: 'some value',
      DateofBirth: 'some value',
      HireDate: 'some value',
      WorkEmail: 'some value',
      FirstName: 'some value',
      LastName: 'some value'
    },
    NationalIDHT: {
      NtionalIDData: {
        NationalIDValues: {
          NationalType: 'some value',
          NationalIDNumber: 'some value'
        }
      }
    },
    AssignmentHT: {
      AssignmentData: {
        Assignment: {
          PersonNumber: 'some value',
          WorkerNumber: 'some value',
          Gender: 'some value',
          ActionName: 'some value',
          HourlySalaried: 'some value',
          SalaryBasis: 'some value',
          ManagerPersonNumber: 'some value',
          ManagerDisplayName: 'some value',
          AssignmentCategory: 'some value',
          AsgState: 'some value',
          JobCode: 'some value',
          Desgination: 'some value',
          Grade: 'some value',
          'Levele-Grade': 'some value',
          Department: 'some value',
          EmployeeType: 'some value',
          BusinessUnit: 'some value',
          BaseLocation: 'some value',
          PhysicalWorkAddress: 'some value'
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
*/
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {max-height: 100% !important; top: 0}
```

```html
<script src="https://bundle.run/object-scan@16.0.0"></script>
```

*Disclaimer*: I'm the author of [object-scan](https://www.npmjs.com/package/object-scan)